# how to display image get from ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=52&entity_type=city&start=0&count=20",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('user-key', '');
    },
    success: function (response) {
        var s = "";
        var i = 0;
        var res_Arr = response.restaurants;
        $.each(res_Arr, function (index, value) {

            var res_img = res_Arr[i].restaurant.featured_image;

            s = s + '<img src="' + res_img + '"/>';
            i = i + 1;
        })
        $('#result').text(s);

    }
});
```

I have tried to search online and tried multiple methods but i can't spot the mistake I made...my console does not show any errors. I wanted to display out as an image but it shows the image link instead...

Comment: please also write error you are getting.

Comment: @wang xinyi you shoold  use append method instead of text method

Comment: Are you setting `user-key` correctly? If so, use `.html()` or `.append()` instead of `.text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `append()` method of `jQuery` for rendering html in web page.

```
 $('#result').append(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=52&entity_type=city&start=0&count=20",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: true,
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('user-key', '');
  },
  success: function (r) {
    $.each(r.restaurants, function (i, v) {
      $("<img>", {
        src: v.featured_image
      }).appendTo($('#result');
    });
  }
});
```

When the AJAX is successful, this will create a new image based on the response using `$.each()` and append each image from the `restaurants` Object.

See more: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

> The `$.each()` function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the `this` keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the `this` value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.) The method returns its first argument, the object that was iterated.